# Create unique id in each click of button using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to create unique id in each click of button using Jquery.Actually i am creating file field by clicking on a button here i need first file field's id will remain constant(`i.e-fileid`) as it is when user will click on a button and the next file field will created the id will change(`i.d-fileid1`) and so on.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile bmargindiv1">
<label for="expcerti" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Publication/Papers Upload your publication/papers certificate.</label>
<ol id="expOl">
   <li>
     <div class="totalaligndiv">
     <div class="col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1">
         <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="expcerti" id="expcerti" />
    </div><div class="col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm " id="Expadd">+</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="Expminus" style="display:none;" >-</button>
  </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ol>                                    
 </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on('click','.btn-success', function () {
           // var i=1;
             $.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
             $('#expOl').append("<li><div class='totalaligndiv'><div class='col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1'><input type='file' class='filestyle' data-size='lg' name='expcerti' ></div><div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm ' id='Expadd'>+</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='minus' style='display:none'>-</button></div><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
            // $('.filestyle').attr("id","expcerti"+i);
             $(this).css('display', 'none');
             $(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
             // i++;
         });
         $(document).on('click','.btn-danger', function () {
             console.log('delete');
             $(this).closest("li").remove();
         });
     });
</script>
```

Check my above code first file field's id is `expcerti`,when one new will be created it should be `expcerti1` and like this it will increment .so that if i have 5 filed i can add 5 file in their respective field.But in my case if i have more file field all file is appending one file field. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a new ID on every click maintain a counter flag.

Let's say `var i = 1;`

Increment this counter on every click `i++`.

Use this counter variable with `id` attribute.

Have modified your code snippet as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i=1;
     $(document).on('click','.btn-success', function () {

         $.getScript("js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js");
         $('#expOl').append("<li><div class='totalaligndiv'><div class='col-md-10 padding-zero bannerimagefilenew bmargindiv1'><input type='file' class='filestyle' data-size='lg' name='expcerti' id='expcerti"+i+"' ></div><div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm ' id='Expadd'>+</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='minus' style='display:none'>-</button></div><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
        // $('.filestyle').attr("id","expcerti"+i);
         $(this).css('display', 'none');
         $(this).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
         i++;
     });
     $(document).on('click','.btn-danger', function () {
         console.log('delete');
         $(this).closest("li").remove();
     });
});
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Appreciate the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `click` event listener to the newly created buttons.

Comment: I want generate new id again.